# Sum/Count Column Data Datatable C# Console App

Tags: c#

I connect to ODBC and populate Data Table.
Depending on the identifie type, INVOICE is + or negative.
I need to sum column two, by each identifier.
I currently use grouping of column 'indentifier, but it is a count so does not take into account a + or -. Simply it counts each go.

Here is example.

IDENTIFIER----| INVOICE

1A557--------|  1 -----------|

2B123--------|  1 -----------|

1A557--------| -1 -----------|

1A557--------|  1 -----------|

2B123--------|  1 -----------|

9C437--------|  1 -----------|

What I want to see is a summary.
This is the result of the above.

1A557--------|  1 -----------|

2B123--------|  2 -----------|

9C437--------|  1 -----------|

this is the code i currently use, which does not do the job.

```
var accountGroups = completeDT_units.AsEnumerable()
                    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<String>("IDENTIFIER"))
                    .Select(grp => new 
                     { 
                          Account = grp.Key, 
                          Count = grp.Count() 
                     });
```

Once this has run I need to see the summary counts.
I have previously copied to another datatable using the following code.

```
var tblAccCounts = new DataTable(); tblAccCounts.Columns.Add("IDENTIFIER"); tblAccCounts.Columns.Add("Totals"); //, typeof(int) foreach (var grp in accountGroups) tblAccCounts.Rows.Add(grp.Account, grp.Count);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use grp.Sum instead of grp.Count. 
Something like:

```
var accountGroups = completeDT_units.AsEnumerable()
                    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<String>("IDENTIFIER"))
                    .Select(grp => new 
                     { 
                          Account = grp.Key, 
                          Count = grp.Sum(row=>row.Field<int>("INVOICE")) 
                     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var accountGroups = completeDT_units.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(row => row.Field<String>("IDENTIFIER"))
                .Select(grp => new 
                 { 
                      Account = grp.Key, 
                      Count = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("INVOICE"))
                 });
```